# Computing a 95% confidence interval on the sum of n i.i.d. exponential random variables

Tags: language-agnostic, math, statistics

Let's in fact generalize to a `c`-confidence interval.  Let the common rate parameter be `a`.  (Note that the mean of an exponential distribution with rate parameter `a` is `1/a`.)

First find the cdf of the sum of `n` such i.i.d. random variables.  Use that to compute a `c`-confidence interval on the sum.  Note that the max likelihood estimate (MLE) of the sum is `n/a`, ie, `n` times the mean of a single draw.

Background:  This comes up in a program I'm writing to make time estimates via random samples.  If I take samples according to a Poisson process (ie, the gaps between samples have an exponential distribution) and `n` of them happen during Activity X, what's a good estimate for the duration of Activity X?  I'm pretty sure the answer is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John D. Cook hinted, the sum of i.i.d. exponential random variables has a gamma distribution.
Here's the cdf of the sum of n exponential random variables with rate parameter a (expressed in Mathematica):

```
F[x_] := 1 - GammaRegularized[n, a*x];
```

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html

The inverse cdf is:

```
Fi[p_] := InverseGammaRegularized[n, 1 - p]/a;
```

The c-confidence interval is then

```
ci[c_, a_, n_] := {Fi[a, n, (1-c)/2], Fi[a, n, c+(1-c)/2]}
```

Here is some code to empirically verify that the above is correct:

```
(* Random draw from an exponential distribution given rate param. *)
getGap[a_] := -1/a*Log[RandomReal[]]

betw[x_, {a_, b_}] := Boole[a <= x <= b]

c = .95;
a = 1/.75;
n = 40;
ci0 = ci[c, a, n];
N@Mean@Table[betw[Sum[getGap[a], {n}], ci0], {100000}]

----> 0.94995
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the sum of independent exponential random variables is a gamma random variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [Chernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff's_inequality), from which you can improvise an interval because the expression is pretty generalizable and you can solve such that the bounded range is wrong < 0.05 of the time.

A Chernoff bound is just about the strongest bound you can get on iid variables without knowing too many moment generating functions.

Comment: Thanks!  If you're up for spelling out exactly how to do that for the case of summed exponential RVs, that would be really awesome.

Comment: Reading more about Chernoff bounds, I'm not convinced this is the right way to get a 95% confidence interval on a random variable.